# Set "Do not autosave" flag in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, autosave

I am working on a shared file which exports a CSV on execution of a macro. The file was created before we used 365 and the script modifies data within the sheet before exporting. Because the data it modifies / deletes is still required it then closes without saving the file - unfortunately 365s autosave feature means that these deletions are committed to the file before it's closure.

Disabling autosave in excel appears to only work on a per-user basis, and as this file is shared I want to force autosave to be off regardless of who opens it. I cannot change the macro as this is locked by my employer.

Is there a setting or flag that can be saved to Excel files in order to prevent  Office 365 from opening with autosave enabled?